# Converting an entire byte array into a single digit hex string

Tags: c#

I have a byte array with 9 elements. I need to convert the entire byte array into a single hex string. 
Above is fairly straightforward to do however, I need to drop leading 0 if an element contains a decimal value less than 16 i.e. F or less. See example below.

```
byte[] myByteArr = {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};
```

"Regular" method to convert the above to hex should give me 0x0A0B0C0D0E0F10111213

What I actually need is 0xABCDEF10111213

Is there a quick method to just drop the upper nibble and take the lower nibble if none of the bits in the upper nibble are set ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you realize that the resulting string is no more convertible back to your original byte array?

Comment: `string.Concat(myByteArr.Select(b => b.ToString("X")))`

Comment: string s = new string(myByteArr.SelectMany(ba => Convert.ToString(ba,16)).ToArray());

Comment: @Steve yes, I am aware. I don't see the need for it to be converted back at the moment. 
Ill try both of your replies and get back to you. Thanks.